# Facebook connect extended permission seems to have issues

Tags: asp.net, facebook, api, permissions

Simply, I've been struggling for 5 days now with facebook api trying to get the user email, bday, about me, etc.. data. I searched online dozen of times, and went through several facebook developer wiki pages but with no hope of finding a solution.

The problem is that I've added the below connect button script, and after a successful login I was able to read very limited user fields of data like first_name, last_name, id and friend's id.

```
<fb:login-button perms="email,user_about_me,user_birthday,user_hometown,user_interests,user_likes,user_location,user_religion_politics" onlogin="auth_using_fb();"></fb:login-button>
```

I'm using Facebook Developer Toolkit 3.02 (for asp.net) and there is nothing fancy, a straight forward code that retrieves an object with all user info using the .getinfo() function.

I tried to post my issue on facebook developers forums, however, I can't register to use the forum since an error related to their capcha prevents me of completing the registration process.

In case you were wondering, I have enabled the migration to the new extended permissions from my applications setting, and added the needed permission attributes to the login button as per the above.

Last but not least, I still can't see the "extended permissions" dialog after accepting the application access at the first step in the connect pop up.

Answer (score 1):

Hey I'm curious if you're including all.js or FeatureLoader.js.php on your page.  It seems the perms attribute only works with all.js, however I have no idea what the difference between the two is.  I guess different versions of the API?